# How can I get href attr from this website?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, href

I'm trying to parse the html of this [web site](https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/buscanormas?conteudo=cess%C3%A3o&dataInicioBusca=17%2F09%2F2018&dataFimBusca=20%2F09%2F2019&tipoDocumento=Todos), and when I get the html_nodes from the supposed links it get the response "" for all the nodes. What am I doing wrong?

```
texto_01 <- read_html(URL)
titulos_noticias <- texto_01 %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_nodes("div") %>% html_nodes("ol") %>% html_nodes("li")  %>% html_nodes("a")
titulos_noticias_texto <- html_attr(titulos_noticias,"href")
titulos_noticias_texto
```

Apreciate the help. Tks a lot, Felipe

Comment: You need to provide `URL` for anyone to be able to debug your problem.

Comment: Brian, hi there! the URL is inside the "web site" href. tks anyway. Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content is loaded dynamically. You can see the page conducting a search and then returning a result set. You need to mimic the actual search request you can find in the network tab. The results returned are in json format. The data of interest is within `r$Rows` and you construct the url by concatenating parts:

```
paste0("https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/exibenormativo?tipo=", item$TipodoNormativoOWSCHCS,'&numero=',as.integer(item$NumeroOWSNMBR))
```

You can use `paste0` and `map_df` to handle this url reconstruction in a loop over the json object returned from  `r$Rows`.

You can see the javascript handling this process at line 6816 of the js file `https://www.bcb.gov.br/BcbModule.cdb75dd11ebbc7b56192.js` found in the sources tab.

[image]

Note that the js is using an already set variable found at line 5609

[image]

---

R:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)

r = jsonlite::read_json('https://www.bcb.gov.br/api/search/app/normativos/buscanormativos?querytext=ContentType:normativo AND contentSource:normativos AND cessão&rowlimit=15&startrow=0&sortlist=Data1OWSDATE:descending&refinementfilters=Data:range(datetime(2018-09-17),datetime(2019-09-20T23:59:59))')

df <- map_df(r$Rows, function(item) {
  data.frame(title = item$title,
             url = paste0("https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/exibenormativo?tipo=", item$TipodoNormativoOWSCHCS,'&numero=',as.integer(item$NumeroOWSNMBR)),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})

head(df)
```

Comment: Hi @QHarr. Tks again my friend. It works here! best, Felipe